# Python: Creating a time rotating log from a config file

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to create a time rotating log from a config file.

This is the example code
It should write a new log file every minute.

```
import logging
import logging.config
import logging.handlers
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':

    logging.config.fileConfig('logging.cfg')
    logger = logging.getLogger("main")
    logger.info("start")
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        logger.info("log more")
```

The "logging.cfg" file looks like this.

I'm trying to guess the syntax from the definition of TimedRotatingFileHandler.

```
[loggers]
keys=root,main

[handlers]
keys=fileHandler, consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=myFormatter

[logger_root]
level=CRITICAL
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_main]
level=INFO
handlers=fileHandler
qualname=main

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=WARN
formatter=myFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
formatter=myFormatter
args=("example.log",)
path='timeexample.log'
when='m'
interval=1
backupCount=5

[formatter_myFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

Starting the code creates a working "example.log" which does not rotate
and doesn't throw any errors.

Any ideas how I can change the config file to get it to rotate?

I'm using python 3.5.2 on windows7 32bit for prototyping and plan to use it on debian in production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little guesswork helped:

Putting the arguments like calling TimedRotatingFileHandler from code works.

```
[handler_fileHandler]
class=logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
formatter=myFormatter
args=("timeexample.log", 'm', 1, 5, )
```

What does not work is using the names:

```
args=("timeexample.log", when='m', interval=1, backupCount=5, )
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your handler like following:

```
   [handler_fileHandler]
    class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
    interval=midnight
    backupCount=1
    formatter=complex
    level=NOTSET
    args=('example.log',)
```

Comment: No parameters "interval", "backupCount". More detail https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/logging/config.py#l163